# Is it possible to go back to using universal apk after splitting in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I decided to split my apks by architecture some time ago, since that would make my app size go down.

However, I've learned the hard way that this makes our help desk's life a looooot harded, since we actually send signed apks to some clients to solve specific problems.

Now, when sending and apk to a client, we need to find out the specific architecture they are using. Our clients cannot uninstall the app, since they might lose sensitive data.

Is it possible to upload only an universal apk to Google Play with our next update? Is Google Play going to handle that? I tried locally doing the update with apks on my phone and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have an answer now.

Universal apks WILL work after updating to a specific architecture, since the universal contains all packages necessary for every architecture to run the app.

**HOWEVER**

You will need to bring your package version very high up. If you're splitting architectures, each architecture likely has it's own package version according to the snippet below, which seems to be default for versioning architectures.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
```

In that case, if your universal apk is around version 100, your armeabi-v7 is gonna be around 1million (1048601, for me).

So if you want your next update to use the universal apk, you'll need your armeabi-v7 users to receive a version above that 1million one.